# Bash: How to persist and restore associative arrays with keys that contain square brackets or other special characters

Tags: bash, special-characters, associative-array, declare

**Problem**

Sourcing the result of `declare -p` for a valid Bash associative array in which keys contain square brackets results in a **bad array subscript** error.

**Testing Procedure**

Do:

```
$ declare -A array
$ key='var[0]'
$ array["$key"]=37
$ echo ${array["$key"]}
37
$ declare -p array > def.sh
$ cat def.sh
declare -A array='(["var[0]"]="37" )'
$ . def.sh
bash: [var[0]]=37: bad array subscript
```

In the above code, note:

- I am able to specify a key that contains square brackets: `var[0]`
- The key is quoted for setters and getters
- I am able to do an assignment using this key
- I am able to get the value from the associative array using this key
- Using `declare -p` I am able to save this definition to a file: `def.sh`
- When sourcing the file `def.sh` an error is emitted.

**My Environment**

- The version of Bash I'm using is **4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)**.
- I am on a **CentOS 7.3.1611 (Core)** server

**Workarounds**

If instead of doing `declare -p array > def.sh` I do instead:

```
{
echo 'declare -A array'
for Key in "${!array[@]}"; do
   EscapedKey="$(sed 's|"|\\"|g' <<<"$Key")"
   echo "array[\"$EscapedKey\"]=${array["$Key"]}"
done
} > def.sh
```

then sourcing the def.sh file works. Note that in the above example, I'm also escaping quote characters that might be a part of the key. I do understand that what I have above is not exhaustive. Because of these complications, I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve such workarounds, if at all possible.

**Question**

Is there some `shopt`,`set -o <option>`, or something else I can do to enable me to persist an associative array whose keys may contain square brackets or other special characters to a file and to later be able to source that file successfully? I am needing a solution that works in my environment above.

Comment: An improvement on the above workaround might include the use of `printf` using `%q`. Again, I am hoping for a solution involving `declare -p` and perhaps some behavior-changing commands; however, if this turns out to be just a bug in Bash 4.2.26(1)-release, then my goal will turn towards a strong workaround solution, perhaps an improvement on what I've shown above.

Comment: I just tested it on an Arch Linux installation with bash 4.4 and there is no such problem - I can use the string just like you intend, no workaround required. I'm trying to find some reference for all changes between 4.2 and 4.4 to see if this was fixed or if later versions just changed behavior.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure this is related, but I have found a slight hint it might have been a bug. I got the sources from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/ - in the archive for bash 4.4's source there's the complete changelog under `CHANGES`. Line 2370: "e.  Fixed several bugs encountered when reading subscripts in associative
    array assignments and expansions.
" - this may be it, but using `shopt -s compat42` didn't seem to have any effect in my environment so I'm not sure how to test without compiling bash anew.

Comment: This was under the bash 4.0 release changes, there's another one: 2559: "h.  When displaying associative arrays, subscripts are now quoted.". What I also noticed is that under my environment, `declare` wrote the same string to the file except the right-hand value was _not_ in single quotes. Everything else is the same.

Comment: Ugh, nevermind the above comments, those changes are before 4.2. There seems to be an option called `complete_fullquote` but it has no effect on this for me. In the changes I found "q.  The declare builtin no longer displays array variables using the compound
    assignment syntax with quotes; that will generate warnings when re-used as
    input, and isn't necessary.
" under the bash 4.3 release notes though.

Comment: @MechaLynx Thanks for checking. It is motivation to upgrade to Bash 4.4. It's a pity that the current CentOS 7.3.1611 distro is still on 4.2.26(1)-release. It's a bureaucratic issue for me to update outside of the `updates` repo.

Comment: I went ahead and started compiling the versions I found on gnu.org, so I'll be able to tell you a bit more in a few minutes. It looks like earlier bash was greedy in matching quotes, while later on it's not so greedy, hence the issue.

Comment: In case you miss it, I added an alternative workaround you might prefer.

Comment: As a final comment on this and a suggestion to anyone that has similar constraints and specifically needs to store key/value pairs en masse, see if your system has `sqlite3`, which would let you comfortably store data of this sort and fetch it as well. Depends on what kind of data you have and the scale of course, but for some it might be a far better alternative than working with `bash`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It's a bug

This is a bug in `bash 4.2`. It's fixed in `4.3`.

I tested this by compiling `bash 4.2`, `4.2.53` and `4.3` from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/ and replicated the steps above. `4.3` behaves like `4.4` - there is no such issue. In bash `4.3` however, `declare` will print

```
declare -A array='(["var[0]"]="37" )'
```

just as `4.2` does. `4.4` does not add the quotes around the right-hand side, instead printing this:

```
declare -A array=(["var[0]"]="37" )
```

This makes *no* difference from what the testing showed.

There a possibly related option in `complete_fullquote` but it was added in `4.4` so it can't be used as a workaround.

It seems that outside of using a version >=`4.3` this needs to be worked around and the one you used is the most straightforward way of doing it.

## A workaround

There is an alternative if you want to avoid the `sed` calls though (tested using `bash 4.2`):

```
function array2file {
  # local variable for the keys
  declare -a keys

  # check if the array exists, to protect against injection
  # by passing a crafted string
  declare -p "$1" >/dev/null || return 1;

  printf "declare -A %s\n" "$1"

  # create a string with all the keys so we can iterate
  # because we can't use eval at for's declaration
  # we do it this way to allow for spaces in the keys, since that's valid
  eval "keys=(\"\${!$1[@]}\")"

  for k in "${keys[@]}"
  do
    printf "%s[\"${k//\"/\\\\\"}\"]=" "$1"
    # the extra quoting here protects against spaces
    # within the element's value - injection doesn't work here
    # but we still need to make sure there's consistency
    eval "printf \"\\\"%s\\\"\n\" \"\${$1[\"${k//\"/\\\"}\"]}\""
  done
}
```

This will properly add quotes around the key and also escape all doublequotes within the key itself. You can place this in a file, which you source. Then use:

```
array2file array > ./def.sh
```

where `array` is whatever array name you've chosen. By redirecting the output you'll get properly quoted keys and you can define your associative array as you did before, then pass it to this function for storage.

## Extra credit

If you change the variable provided to the first `printf` inside the `for` loop from `$1` to `${2:-$1}` and do the same at the `printf` at the top, then you can optionally create the definition of a new array with the 2nd argument as its name, allowing renaming of sorts. This will only happen if you provide 2 strings instead of one (quoted of course). The setup allows for this to be done easily, so I've added it here.

This would let you work around cases where interfacing with existing code can be difficult with a predefined function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughtful solution. I am going to incorporate it into the open-source Bash scripting platform I'm working on at eggsh.com. Upvoting with my thanks!

Comment: @SteveAmerige np, but can you explain the edit? I've tested both the previous version and this one using a test array under bash 4.2 and they seem to function identically - I'm curious about whether you encountered some issue. By the way, I accidentally turned a parenthesis into a bracket while writing the code in the post, it has been corrected.

Comment: @SteveAmerige nevermind, saw the comment on your edit. However, the issue still remains, they function identically on test strings, including the one you had in the comment (which gets turned into `array["0"]="["com.acme".var[0]]=73"` that strangely works, but works with both). I omitted escaping all kinds of special characters because they can be treated in the same way quotes are, whereas the issues with spaces and injection were more complicated and subtle.